# Angular show-hide flickers

Tags: angularjs

I'm switching the visibility of 2 elements when clicking them. A very simple use case:

```
<div ng-hide="filtersOpened"
     ng-click="filtersOpened=true">
    filters (opened)
</div>
<div ng-show="filtersOpened"
     ng-click="filtersOpened=false">
    filters (closed)
</div>
```

The change happens, but it flickers so that for a very short moment I see **both** elements together.

How can I make the change behave nicer, smoother, without the flickering? I've read about `ng-cloack` but doesn't seem like it's related since I'm not using a template.

Comment: I don't know where you are testing... but this plunker works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/DHFEpfO1Wc5jDdl0pSht?p=preview

Comment: it doesn't flicker for me, even on large applications with lots of contents inside the divs

Comment: @LucasRodriguez I know, works for me too in plunker. But for some reason in my app it doesn't

Comment: @gyc my app is quite large... I thought it might be related to the number of watchers, but even when I hide some complex area of the app to reduce the watchers, just for testing, this specific problem still persists...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try ng-if instead:

```
<div ng-if="filtersOpened" ng-click="filtersOpened=true">
    filters (opened)
</div>
<div ng-if="!filtersOpened" ng-click="filtersOpened=false">
    filters (closed)
</div>
```